# CSS position child top at x pixels from bottom of parent

Tags: css

I'd like to have a child div which top is only visible for 10 pixels at the bottom of a parent div (with the rest of it outside the parent div). How can I do that?

**Edit:** I had not considered the CSS calc function, as suggested by Temani Afif. So here is my CSS. However the child is at the top of its parent. I must be missing something.

```
.parent_div {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;  
}

.child_div {
    position:absolute;
    top: calc(100%-10px);
    left: 25%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdde3;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: top:calc(100% - 10px) ?

Comment: It's not rude to ask you to **demonstrate** what you have tried. How do we know *what* you have done if you don't show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(100% - 10px);
  border:1px solid green;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<p>
parent div
</p>
<div class="child">
<p>
child div
</p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like that I only needed to have used some spaces in `calc(100%-10px)`